# Correcting the position of modified checkbox and radio buttons and labels

Tags: html, css

I modified the styling of checkbox and radio buttons with CSS, but now the position of buttons and labels scatters, doesn't look like before modifing... I don't know what's wrong with that or how to fix it, because I never modified checkboxes and radio buttons before.

EDIT:

Label still overlaps with checkbox.

CSS:

```
    input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
   display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label {
   width: 8px;
   height: 8px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   display: inline-block;
   background: white;
   border-top: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128);
   border-left: 1px solid rgb(128,128,128);
   border-right: 1px solid rgb(200,200,200);
   border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(200,200,200);
   margin-top: 7px;
   padding-left: 10px;
}
```

I thought I may split up input[type="checkbox" and label, instead of doing input[type="checkbox"] + label, but then styling on checkbox didn't work.

Comment: Can you post it into a jsfiddle?

Comment: Sure. Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/32Cjq/

Comment: So what do you want it to look like? Everything sequentially from top to bottom?

Comment: From left to right. First, there's whole form. I have 4 divs in it - 1st div are text fields (imie, nazwisko...) - text fields should be viewed from top to bottom. But there's 2nd div which contains checkboxes. Again, content in div should be viewed from top to bottom, but divs themself should be viewed from left to right. I'll try to resize content area, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assigned content area (`width: 8px; height: 8px`); is too small for all the content to fit in the div. Therefore, they're overlapping on one another.

[image]

A recommended fix is instead of assigning a deliberate `width: 8px` just assign `input[type="checkbox"]` without `label` with a `margin-left: 20px` or some other pixel amount. http://jsfiddle.net/32Cjq/2/

Here's further clarification that's much better 
[on styling labels and checkboxes, with your issue addressed](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/web-design-html-and-css/threads/455906/styling-labels-and-checkboxes-in-chrome)

Comment: I see where the problem is. I added width: 60px to .form-wybory-margines, and divs are not coliding with themselfs anymore. But label still overlaps checkbox. I thought I can fix it by styling label itself... I modified my first post and put the code there.

Comment: Haha, well here's an updated Jfiddle to solve the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/32Cjq/2/ I'll update the answer